# Crafty ways to make super efficient R vector processing?

Tags: r, performance, optimization, vector

I have a very simple assignment for a project that requires processing a large amount of information; my professor's first words were "this will take a while to run" so I figured it'd be a good opportunity to spend that time i would be running my program making a super efficient one :P

Basically, I have a input file where each line is either a node or details. It might look something like:

```
#NODE1_length_17_2309482.2394832.2
val1    5     18
val2    6     21
val3    100   23
val4    9     6
#NODE2_length_1298_23948349.23984.2
val1    2    293
...
```

and so on. Basically, I want to know how I can efficiently use R to either output, line by line, something like:

```
NODE1_length_17   val1   18
NODE1_length_17   val2   21
...
```

So, as you can see, I would want to node name, the value, and the third column of the value line. I have implemented it using an ultra slow for loop that uses strsplit a whole bunch of times, and obviously this is not ideal. My current implementation looks like:

```
   nodevals <- which(substring(data, 1, 1) == "#") # find lines with nodes
   vallines <- which(substring(data, 1, 3) == "val")
   out <- vector(mode="character", length=length(vallines))
   for (i in vallines) {

      line_ra <- strsplit(data[i], "\\s+")[[1]]
      ... and so on using a bunch of str splits and pastes to reformat
      out[i] <- paste(node, val, value, sep="\t")
   }
```

Does anybody know how I can optimize this using data frames or crafty vector manipulations?

EDIT: I'm implementing vecor wise splitting for everything, and so far I've found that the main thing I can't split correctly is the names of each node. I'm trying to do something like,

```
names <- data[max(nodes[nodelines < vallines])]
```

where nodes are the names of each line containing a node and vallines are the numbers of each line containing a val. The return vector should have the same number of elements as vallines. The goal is to find the maximum nodelines that is less than the line number of vallines for each vallines. Any thoughts?

Comment: `strsplit` is vectorized. You should not be running it over each and every "val" row. You can run it as one block on an entire vector.

Comment: Do you have to do this data transformation in R? Because the `awk` utility could do it very quickly on the command line...

Comment: Here's the awk version: `awk '$0~"^#"{sub("_[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*\\.[0-9]*","",$0);V=substr($0,2,9999)};$0!~"^#"{print V,$1,$3}' < shape.txt` ; if the line starts with a `#`, update the current `V`, stripping off the `#` and the dotted numbers, otherwise print the first and third fields with the current `V` value.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `data.table` package - it has very fast string split function `tstrsplit`.

```
library(data.table)

#read from file
data <- scan('data.txt', 'character', sep = '\n')

#create separate objects for nodes and values
dt <- data.table(data)
dt[, c('IsNode', 'NodeId') := list(IsNode <- substr(data, 1, 1) == '#', cumsum(IsNode))]
nodes <- dt[IsNode == TRUE, list(NodeId, data)]
values <- dt[IsNode == FALSE, list(data, NodeId)]

#split string and join back values and nodes
tmp <- values[, tstrsplit(data, '\\s+')]
values <- data.table(values[, list(NodeId)], tmp[, list(val = V1, value = V3)], key = 'NodeId')
res <- values[nodes]
```